# Using Shell32.dll SHGetFolderPath Function in Custom Action Wix

Tags: c#, wix

I have to use SHGetFolderPath function of Shell32.dll inside C# Custom Action. Basically what I am trying to do is get the value of Property passed to MSI as:

```
msiexec /i file.msi IPADDRESS="127.0.0.1"
```

and write the value in some config file given by the **SHGetFolderPath**

I tried following code:

```
namespace SetupCA
{

    public class CustomActions
    {

        [CustomAction]
        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SHGetFolderPath(
            IntPtr hwndOwner,           // Handle to an owner window.
            Int32 nFolder,              // A CSIDL value that identifies the folder whose path is to be retrieved.
            IntPtr hToken,              // An access token that can be used to represent a particular user.
            UInt32 dwFlags,             // Flags to specify which path is to be returned. It is used for cases where 
            // the folder associated with a CSIDL may be moved or renamed by the user. 
            StringBuilder pszPath); 
        public static ActionResult WriteFileToDisk(Session session)
        {

            session.Log("Begin WriteFileToDisk");

            const int CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 0x001c;
            StringBuilder path1 = new StringBuilder(256);
            SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, IntPtr.Zero, 0, path1);
            session.Log("LOCAL APP_DATA PATH " + path1.ToString());

            string ipAddress = session["IPADDRESS"];
            //string port = session["PORT"];
            //string path = session["PATH"];  // PATH is of format C:\\lpaa\\
            string path = path1.Replace(@"\", @"\\").ToString();
            path = path + @"\\lpa\\config\\";
            session.Log("LOCAL APP_DATA PATH NOW MODIFIED " + path.ToString());
            string temp = @"
{{
 ""logpoint_ip"" : ""{0}"" 
}}";
            string config = string.Format(temp, ipAddress);
            session.Log("Config Generated was " + config);
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path + "lpa.config");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                session.Log(e.ToString());
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "lpa.config", config);
            session.Log("Ending WriteFileToDisk");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles successfully but when making a Wix Installer and installing it gives error

```
 A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `[CustomAction]` attribute is in the wrong place; Shouldn't it be on `WriteFileToDisk` instead of `SHGetFolderPath`?

Better yet, read [`session["LocalAppDataFolder"]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369768.aspx) instead to skip the P/Invoke.

Comment: Thank You. Both of the way worked. But how is the C# Custom action getting **LocalAppDataFolder** even though it is not being passed as Property to CA.

Comment: @SarvagyaPant Windows Installer sets a lot of properties automatically. This is one of the [System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx#system_folder_properties)